# How to cover IF/ELSE condition with Angular 4 Jasmine unit test case

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular4-router, angular4-httpclient

Help me to cover the IF/Else coverage and the method returning HTTP response and also constructor to cover branch coverage for router and Appconfig service for **Jasmine Unit test cases**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can mock the http response by using MockBackend 
Reference: https://angular.io/api/http/testing/MockBackend

You can easily define your own response and test all if/else

```
// before each test 
beforeEach(() => {
    this.injector = ReflectiveInjector.resolveAndCreate([
      {provide: ConnectionBackend, useClass: MockBackend},
      {provide: RequestOptions, useClass: BaseRequestOptions},
      Http,
      // other dependencies like Router / AppConfig
    ]);
    this.authenticationService = this.injector.get(AuthenticationService);
    this.backend = this.injector.get(ConnectionBackend) as MockBackend;
    this.backend.connections.subscribe((connection: any) => this.lastConnection = connection);   
});


// in your test
const mockErrorResponse = {status: 200};
this.lastConnection.mockRespond(new Response(new ResponseOptions({body: JSON.stringify(mockErrorResponse)})));
tick();
```